# UIButton pressed Insert Current Time in Text Field using Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a UIButton put the current time in a text field when pressed?  Here is the textfield and UIButton code I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var f1TextField: UITextField!    

@IBAction func markf1(_ sender: UIButton) {         
    timeatf1TextField.becomeFirstResponder;         
    timeatf1TextField.text! = "Time". // This is where I want the current time to go!
}
```

Comment: What do you need, do you want to know how to get the current time or how to update your text filed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring the variable as f1TextField and calling it as timeatf1TextField. To get current time see the code below...

```
@IBOutlet var f1TextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func markf1(_ sender: Any) {

    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss a"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)

    f1TextField.text = dateString
}
```

Comment: Thank so much.  I was very close to that but could not quite get it.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you were looking for than mark it as approved and sure give it a thumbs-up :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@IBAction func markf1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //Dateformat you want
    let date = Date()
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    timeatf1TextField.text = dateString
}
```